# mysql .net connector Apostrophe issue

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I'm having problems, with MySQL, with the following code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient  'Last version 6.9.9.0 ADO.Net driver for MySQL
    Dim commandSQL As MySqlCommand
    connMySQL.Open()
    commandSQL = connMySQL.CreateCommand
    commandSQL.Connection = connMySQL

   commandSQL.CommandText = "UPDATE t_tesordacq SET COD_FOR=@COD_FOR WHERE 
               YEAR_DOC = 2017 And NUM_DOC = 123" With                     
              commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_FOR",txtCodFor.Text)
   End With
   commandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
   commandSQL.Parameters.Clear()
```

When I insert a text in the **txtCodFor** field, which contains an **apostrophe** (ex: I'm), the code goes wrong (*Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'\'test' WHERE YEAR_DOC = 2017 And NUM_DOC = 123,* ).`

I also tried replacing the text with double apostrophe: **txtCodFor.Text.Replace("'", "''")** but there was nothing to do.
Also, if I insert a backslash, it is duplicated!

I've seen that if I remove the "**NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES**" option, from sql_mode in my.ini, everything works correctly.
Unfortunately I can not permanently remove this option for compatibility with a written application in VB6 (ODBC-connected)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why have you tagged this with C#?

Comment: because I also accept code examples in c #

Answer (score 1):

The `MySqlParameter` object will escape `'` with the sequence `\'` by default. This is incompatible with the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` server option, which is causing the syntax error. As far as I know, there is no option to override this behaviour (in the client).

You will have to avoid using a parameterised query, but instead construct a string literal following the rules in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html); specifically, surround the string with single quotes and escape each embedded single quote by doubling it.

```
commandSQL = connMySQL.CreateCommand
commandSQL.Connection = connMySQL
commandSQL.CommandText = "UPDATE t_tesordacq SET COD_FOR='" &
    COD_FOR.Replace("'", "''") &
    "' WHERE YEAR_DOC = 2017 And NUM_DOC = 123"
commandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work -

```
var codeFor = txtCodFor.Text.Replace(@"'", @"\'");
commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_FOR", codeFor);
```

Escaping the ' in the value before you pass it.

Comment: @MarcoZecchi - can you try the amended code please?

Comment: I tried to enter the code: abc'j 
The result is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'j', WHERE YEAR_DOC = 2017 And NUM_DOC = 123

I tried with this replace Replace("'", "''") , i ave the error ....syntax to use near'\'j', ...